# Inflate exeption with AppcompatTextView only for a specific activity caused by NoclassDefFound error

Tags: android, build, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing problems with `inflate exception`  with `AppCompatTextView` caused by class not found exception. This exception occurs `only at my third activity`. Even if this class is also in first and second activity.  I have read about `possible solutions like: clean and Rebuild my project,uninstall and reinstall app on emulator,disable instant Run (it's not possible considering my Android Studio version), enable  Multidex` but none of these solutions seems to work for me.
Thanks for helping me

my logcat is...

```
 08-01 22:04:31.500  15991-15991/com.fornapp.wordgame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.fornapp.wordgame, PID: 15991
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fornapp.wordgame/com.fornapp.wordgame.Game}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #124: Binary XML file line #124: Error inflating class AppCompatTextView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #124: Binary XML file line #124: Error inflating class AppCompatTextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at com.fornapp.wordgame.Game.onCreate(Game.java:311)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #124: Error inflating class AppCompatTextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at com.fornapp.wordgame.Game.onCreate(Game.java:311)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.AppCompatTextView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fornapp.wordgame-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fornapp.wordgame-2/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:677)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at com.fornapp.wordgame.Game.onCreate(Game.java:311)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.AppCompatTextView
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 29 more
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

This is the layout containing AppCompatTextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/Flipper">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.50"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.10"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:id="@+id/playMode"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            style="@style/titles"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.10"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/cup"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cup"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cup"

            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:id="@+id/topScore"/>

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.12"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/to_guess"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bordergrid"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:gravity="center">



            <ProgressBar
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:max="1000"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:progress="1000"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress"
                android:secondaryProgress="1000"
                android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
                />




            <GridView
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/to_choose">
        </GridView>

        </FrameLayout>



        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:id="@+id/graphic_lives"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/three_lives"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/SceneFromLevelToLevel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">
    <AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/StringLevelComplete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageLevelComplete"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/StringLevelComplete"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cartel"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/NextButton"
    android:layout_below="@id/StringLevelComplete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_border"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/forward"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    </ViewFlipper>
```

Here is my module Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fornapp.wordgame"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    }
```

and that's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fornapp.wordgame" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".OptionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_options"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Game" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".EndGame" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add code please